# Create computed property on the content of an item in a subcollection

Tags: knockout.js

I'm building a menu and I've got a `category` object and it has an observable array of `menuitem`s.

I created an observable property on the `category` which is `true` when at least one of the `menuitem`s in the observable array has an `active` property of `true`.

(so the `category` has a computed property named `active` which has to be `true` when at least one of the items in the observable array of menuitems has the `active` property set to `true`)

That `active` property on the `menuitem` is an observable `boolean`.

Now it seems that the computed property on the category doesn't change when the property on it's child (menu)item changes.

I can see the value of the child (menu) item changing, but the computed property on the category does not (I do a console log in the computed property at this moment, and i just doesn't log that the computed property gets evaluated).

Is that by design, or am I doing something wrong here...

PS we are using version 2.3 of KO

Answer (score 1):

> or am I doing something wrong here...

It's kind of hard to tell if you don't show any code, but it *does* seem like it.

Here's an implementation of the behavior you describe that does exactly what you expect it to. Since you're using knockout 2.3, you'll see the subscription trigger *every time* the computed re-evaluates. Notice that in later versions of knockout, it will only trigger if the value actually changes.

```js
var Category = function() {

  this.menuItems = ko.observableArray([
    { active: ko.observable(false) },
    { active: ko.observable(false) },
    { active: ko.observable(true)  },
    { active: ko.observable(false) }
  ]);
  
  this.active = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.menuItems().some(function(subMenu) {
      return subMenu.active();
    });
  }, this);
  
  this.active.subscribe(console.log);
  
};

ko.applyBindings(new Category());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="checked: active">Parent active

<ul data-bind="foreach: menuItems">
  <li>
    <label>(active <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: active">)</label>
    <span data-bind="text: 'Menu ' + $index()"></span>
    
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a great repro of what my code is. One thing I noticed is that you end the computed with `, this);`. What is that for?

Comment: The function passed to the `ko.computed` isn't automatically called with the right `this` context. Knockout allows you to pass the context you want the function to run in and uses it internally via `.call`. Other ways to bind the function to the instance are via `var self = this` or `.bind(this)`